# Meaning of *(&a – i) in a for loop. Is that multiplication?

Tags: c

I am preparing for an upcoming exam when I came across this:

> ```
> char a = 'a';
> char b = 'b';
> int ai[] = { 1, 2 };
> int i = 0;
> ```
>
> Assume that word size is 32 bits, that an int is 32 bits and that memory allocations are made in the reverse order to the declarations starting at address location 68.
>
> Draw a diagram that shows the effect of executing the following lines of code.
>
> ```
> for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
>     *(&a – i) = 'z';
> ```

It might sound weird, but I am a newbie to C and it is the first time I've seen multiplication of a for loop. Explanation to this for loop and the multiplication applied to it would be appreciated.

Comment: `*(&a – i)` is a terrible idea, given the code.

Comment: That is not multiplication, that is dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: There is no multiplication, that's the unary prefix pointer dereferencing operator. You need to study C basics.

Comment: A recipe for asssuming that undefined behaviour can somehow be quantified.

Comment: There's no multiplication here. It's a poor example that omits the brackets around the body of the for-loop. The `*` is for dealing with pointers.

Comment: I would totally draw some noses and some demons.

Comment: This will be edxplained in every C book. You just should not skip chapters. And that code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: With `i` other than 0, `*(&a – i)` is undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: @chux why is that undefined behavior?

Comment: C11dr §6.5.6 8 details the addition of a pointer and an integer. "When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, ... "  `*(&a – i)` meets none of the defined criteria, so the behavior is undefined  (UB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can assume that this is a theoretical question, which, given additional assumptions not defined within the question (i.e. byte order, padding) - the question is answerable. But, as @chux pointed, there are standards against such behavior. For, if it were allowed, the code yields to  corruption of stack memory. As an exam question, it is actually asking you to diagram which memory is being corrupted.

If I interpret the question correctly, one possible representation of the memory (assuming integers are LSB, there is 1 byte padding, and reverse order for declarations):

`| Addr | Value | Desc                           |
| ---- | ----- | ------------------------------ |
|   55 | 0x00  | // int i = 0;                  |
|   56 | 0x00  |                                |
|   57 | 0x00  |                                |
|   58 | 0x00  |                                |
|   59 | 0x01  | // int ai[] = { 1, 2 };        |
|   60 | 0x00  |                                |
|   61 | 0x00  |                                |
|   62 | 0x00  |                                |
|   63 | 0x02  |                                |
|   64 | 0x00  |                                |
|   65 | 0x00  |                                |
|   66 | 0x00  |                                |
|   67 | 0x62  |  // char b = 'b';              |
|   68 | 0x61  |  // char a = 'a';              |`

The loop, unrolled, evaluates to:

`[68] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[67] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[66] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[65] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[64] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[63] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[62] = 0x7a; // 'z';
[61] = 0x7a; // 'z';`

So memories represent by variables, a, b and parts of the ai[] array will be corrupted. (Incorporated @chux observation about endianess. Also, I adjusted the order in which elements of the ai[] appears as per @chux and @Peter A. Schneider comments.)

`| Addr | Value | Desc                                      |
| ---- | ----- | ----------------------------------------- |
|   55 | 0x08  | // int i = 8;                             |
|   56 | 0x00  |                                           |
|   57 | 0x00  |                                           |
|   58 | 0x00  |                                           |
|   59 | 0x01  | // int ai[] = { 0x7a7a0001, 0x7a7a7a7a }; |
|   60 | 0x00  |                                           |
|   61 | 0x7a  |                                           |
|   62 | 0x7a  |                                           |
|   63 | 0x7a  |                                           |
|   64 | 0x7a  |                                           |
|   65 | 0x7a  |                                           |
|   66 | 0x7a  |                                           |
|   67 | 0x7a  | // char b = 'z';                          |
|   68 | 0x7a  | // char a = 'z';                          |`

Comment: Certainly `59 | 0x02  | // int ai[] = { 1, 2 }; ` is amiss.  I'd expect `59 | 0x01 ...` Comment `// int ai[] = { 0x02007a7a, 0x7a7a7a7a };` looks wrong, inconsistent  endian.  Suggest "assuming integers are LSB" --> "assuming integers are little endian"

Comment: @chux is right: While the question defines that stack allocation proceeds towards smaller addresses, resulting on the defined entities residing in in memory in the reverse order of declaration, *arrays are compound but single objects* whose members are arranged in the order specified by the standard. Specifically, the address of array elements can *always* be computed by *adding* the index to the address of the first element, which numerically equals the array's address. Therefore, the *first* element (not the second) of `ai` has the 0x02 byte in it somewhere. Btw, very lucid answer otherwise.

Comment: To elaborate, I think the memory layout you gave in the first table for the array // int ai[] = { 1, 2 };` is reversed: it must be *0x01* at address 59 for `ai[0]`, and 0x02 at address 63 for `ai[1]`. In the second table, consequently the comment is wrong: it must be `// int ai[] = { 0x7a7a0002 , 0x7a7a7a7a};` because `ai[0]` resides at the lower address,  independent of endianness. Here that address is 59 with the (endianness dependent) contents 0x02,

Answer (score 3):

That's not multiplication, that's dereferencing a pointer. However, `*(&a – i)` is already undefined behaviour the moment `i > 0`. In your particular question however where there are unicorns and UB is a thing of the past and where you have to assume variable allocations are done in the reverse order they're declared and there is no padding whatsoever this would overwrite the variables `b` and `ai`.

Comment: Well, it is undefined behavior *in all circumstances*. Of course behavior covered under this term includes overwriting values that happen to reside at the computed addresses. But compilers are free to simply ignore all code after that expression, etc., and have done so for example when strict aliasing was violated (and the programmer's intention was much clearer).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Very true, I'm just answering the case of the senseless exam question.